# Is it possible to have a method that can return different class objects in Java depending on the condition?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

How can I make a method to return different immutable class objects depending on some conditions?

If it is not possible, is there an alternative to tackle this question?

```java
public class ArriveEvent {
    private final List<Server> list;
    private final Customer cust;

    ArriveEvent(Customer ppl, List<Server> listing){
        this.list = listing;
        this.cust = ppl;
    }

    PutSomethingHere? execute(){
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.3f %d arrives", cust.giveArrival(), cust.giveID());
    }
}
```

The main question is for `execute()` to return different statements depending on the condition of an immutable `class Server`, in the list, which have different attributes, such as availability or if there is another customer in line.

```
private final boolean avail;
private final boolean anyoneWaitingInLine;
```

This is the requirement:

```
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, false, 0), new Server(2, true, false, 0))).execute() // Two servers: (1) busy; (2) free
$.. ==> 0.500 1 served by 2
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, false, 0), new Server(2, true, false, 0))).execute().execute()
$.. ==> 1.500 1 done serving by 2
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, true, 5.0), new Server(2, false, false, 10.0))).execute() // Both servers busy, (1) has waiting customers
$.. ==> 0.500 1 waits to be served by 2
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, true, 5.0), new Server(2, false, false, 10.0))).execute().execute()
$.. ==> 10.000 1 served by 2
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, true, 5.0), new Server(2, false, false, 10.0))).execute().execute().execute()
$.. ==> 11.000 1 done serving by 2
jshell> new ArriveEvent(new Customer(1, 0.5), Arrays.asList(new Server(1, false, true, 5.0), new Server(2, false, true, 10.0))).execute() // Both busy with waiting customer
$.. ==> 0.500 1 leaves
```

My original idea was to create multiple classes `servedby`, `wait`, `doneserving`, `leave` that `extends` the `ArrivalEvent class` as I would need different `toStrings()` depending on the situation of the servers and customers, then when I run an `execute()`, it would return different classes that extended ArrivalEvent class depending on the condition of the servers and customers and have another overriding `execute()` which returns a class among them.

Comment: *Is it possible to have a method that can return different class objects in java depending on the condition?* - Yes, only if those different classes will be extending some common base class/type.

Comment: Yes, my original plan is to create "servedby", "wait", "doneserving", "leave" that extends the ArrivalEvent class and execute would return one of these subclasses depending on the condition of server inside the list, how would I do so?

Comment: see the answer.

Comment: Can you move that information to your question (***without*** "Edit:", "Update", etc. - the question should appear as if it was written today)? [Stack Overflow is *not* a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63997684/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Yes, my original plan is to create "servedby", "wait", "doneserving", "leave" that extends the ArrivalEvent class and execute would return one of these subclasses depending on the condition of server inside the list, how would I do so?*

First of all, few notes about your existing code:

1. Always respect [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), name your classes with *PascalCase* and methods - with *camelCase*. Example from your comment would be `doneserving`, which should be `DoneServing`;
2. According to the same convention, try your best to have *Noun* as your class name;
3. your `.toString()` uses `giveArrival()` and `giveID()`, which are not defined in your code, so your snippet would not compile;
4. You don't provide the class definitions for `Customer` and `Server`.

Now, after considering all this, if we assume that you have all the necessary classes in your original code (named accordingly), your working code would look like this:

```java
class ServedBy extends ArrivalEvenet {
    //...
}

class Wait extends ArrivalEvenet {
    //...
}

class DoneServing extends ArrivalEvenet {
    //...
}

class Leave extends ArrivalEvenet {
    //...
}

class ArrivalEvenet {

}

public class ArriveEvent {

    private final List<Server> list;
    private final Customer cust;

    ArriveEvent(Customer ppl, List<Server> listing){
        this.list = listing;
        this.cust = ppl;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.3f %d arrives", cust.giveArrival(), cust.giveID());
    }

    ArrivalEvenet execute(ArrivalEvenet object) {
        if (/*your condition*/) {
            return new ServedBy(); //alternatively create your object
        } else if (/*your condition*/) {
            return new Wait(); //alternatively create your object
        } else if (/*your condition*/) {
            return new DoneServing(); //alternatively create your object
        } else if (/*your condition*/) {
            return new Leave(); //alternatively create your object
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong type has been provided");
        }
    }
}
```

`/*your condition*/` will look something like `list.get(...)==...`

Comment: How does does java work such that returning a new ServedBy()/ Wait() doesn't give an error as it is not does not return the type ArrivalEvent?

Comment: Please do some research yourself. You can read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)  to start learning about *Inheritance*. If *Dog* extends *Animal*, this means, that *Dog* IS an *Animal*. So, if your methods says *I return Animal*, it can return anything that IS an *Animal* (i.e. that extends *Dog*).

Comment: Ah I see, I did read about it previously but it seems i had a misunderstanding of the topic, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may use refactoring here

```
public <T> T execute(){
    Object obj = getObject(ArriveEvent, ArriveEvent.getClass()) // Pass element as per condition
}

public static <T> T getObject(Object o, Class<T> type){
    if(type.isInstance(o)){
        return type.cast(o)
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This thing won't even compile. Also, you should explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks to mention I should give more explanation.   This is working code from one of my applications.  Based on question ,expectation is to get different objects based on conditions for example ClassA,ClassB .So, if for condition1 ,I pass getObject(ClassA,ClassA.class)..I get object of class A. and I can access all methods of class A using refactoring. vice-versa for classB.Hope it helps